# IPX protocol - generating frames

Tags: frame, ethernet

Wanted to write better AI for the game Red Alert 2. Game uses IPX protocol for multiplayer. If i'm right, IPX protocol is on Layer 2, so there is only ETH frame without destination/source IP or destination/source Port, so game is running via it's own protocol. Therefore, i could analyse this protocol and programe AI, that would simulate real player. Do you think, tak it is realistic idea? Is there any way how to "generate" and send IPX packet (ETH frame)?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way how to "generate" and send IPX packet (ETH frame)?

IPX is a layer 3 protocol; but it doesn't contain IP addresses, because it's not an "IP" (internet protocol).

Assuming you're on Windows, the Winsock library is supposed to support IPX: see [Winsock IPX/SPX Annex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741399(VS.85).aspx).

IPX is a packet-oriented (not stream-oriented), unreliable (not guaranteed delivery) protocol: like UDP, instead of like TCP.

I expect that using Winsock for IPX is like using Winsock for UDP, except using `SOCKADDR_IPX` etc.

> Do you think, tak it is realistic idea?

If you'll need to reverse-engineer the contents of the packets, using only a packet sniffer, then I expect that will be difficult.